# Access is denied error for WMI for a network PC

Tags: windows, networking, vbscript, wmi

Below is a WMI script which gives local path of network share.It gives error

```
Script: D:\Desktop\nvt.vbs
Line:   11
Char:   1
Error:  Access is denied. 
Code:   80070005
Source:     SWbemLocator
```

Here is code

```
strPath = "\\pc132\d"

strPath = Replace(strPath, "\\", "")

arrPath = Split(strPath, "\")

strComputer = arrPath(0)
strShare = arrPath(1)

Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") 
Set objWMIService = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer("PC132", "\\pc132\root\cimv2", "username", "password")


Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Share Where Name = '" & strShare & "'")

For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo objItem.Path
Next
```

I do use admin login of the pc.WMI,RPC,RPC locator etc service are running.
I have given full permission in COM Security in dcomcnfg .Also i have given permission for root/cimv2 etc.But still getting the error.So please help me on this.
I have already refered http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394603(v=vs.85).aspx  and some other links

Comment: What were the results when you ran `WMIDiag`? Are all required ports accessible on the remote host? Check with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) if all packets are going through. Also try disabling the Windows-Firewall on both hosts (if it's enabled). Do you see anything in the security eventlog?

Comment: No error in WMIDiag and also firewall is OFF

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure client give permission run wmi script from remote. To allow wmi remote on client run below command :

netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes